# Can't install the ATI fglrx driver, using a ATI RV635 - Mobility Radeon HD 3650

Tags: installation, ati

I'm having problems with the ATI driver. It says that the system is not using the Proprietary Controller. I can't activate it and there aren't any suggestions on how to solve this.

I saw on another post an answer that recommends installing 'linux ati catalyst driver'from http://support.amd.com/fr/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx

Should I do that? Or is there a way around this.

Thank you!

Comment: What card do you have?

Comment: I did the 'lspci' command and I got :

VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV635 [Mobility Radeon HD 3650]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the [ATI drivers Wiki](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware) you card is no longer supported by the ATI fglrx drivers, you can still use the open source available with Ubuntu.

I recommend that you remove the fglrx packages and remove your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file. That will revert to the open source drivers.

Comment: As long as it works, it's fine with me. :)

Answer (score -1):

You may want to install the binary driver manually from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI